# Polymer data binding to text from Firebase snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, data-binding, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

I am working on a project that makes use of Firebase Authentication and `<firebase-query>` from the `polymerfire` elements. I use data binding in many places throughout my application and never had this problem.

I bind the user object, which was created when a user authenticated, in many places to receive the name of my users. The following code shows a custom element. In there, I am trying to bind besides the user object the Firebase snapshot to a property that is of type `Object`.

When I `console.log()` the `vidobj` property, it displays the whole object. However, I am unable to bind it to my text. Although, the same works for the user object property.

I believe this has something to do with the lifecycle in Polymer. Should the property not update automatically even though the value might be created later?

The following screenshot displays the two `console.log`'s
with the content of the `vidobj`:

[image]

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-singlevideo">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <firebase-auth user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>
    <iron-localstorage
      id="localstorage"
      name="my-app-storage"
      value="{{localUserDetails}}">
    </iron-localstorage>

    <h1>Name: [[user.displayName]]</h1>
    <h1>Video Title: [[vidobj.title]]</h1>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
     is: 'my-singlevideo',

     properties: {
       user: {
         type: Object,
       },
       localUserDetails: {
         type: Object,
       },
       vidobj: {
         type: Object,
       },
     },

     ready: function() {

       this.$.localstorage.reload();
       var videoId = this.localUserDetails.lastClickedVid;

       firebase.database().ref('/videos/' + videoId).once('value',   function(snapshot) {
        this.vidobj = snapshot.val();
        console.log(this.vidobj);
        console.log(this.vidobj.title);
       });  
     },

   });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: The data binding should be updated automatically after setting `this.vidobj`. The problem might be in the object itself. Can you update the question to show the contents of `snapshot.val()`? Is `vidobj` set by anything else (via a binding, or some callback not shown in the question)?

Comment: @tony19 thanks for the quick response. I added the console log with the vidobj. The code shows everything related to the vidobj.
I am getting a key from the localstorage and with that i am creating the firebase database request. The result ends up inside the vidobj.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. The callback's context. is not bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Firebase callback's context is not bound to your Polymer object, so you're actually setting `vidobj` on the outer context (usually the `Window` object).

To fix this, use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this:

```
ready: function() {
  // ...
  firebase.database().ref('/videos/' + videoId).once('value',
    function(snapshot) {
      this.vidobj = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.vidobj);
      console.log(this.vidobj.title);
    }.bind(this)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fore the corrections and solution. I had to read up on the bind() function. If someone else with lacking knowledge should come across this. Here is a link from the MDN which explains it: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @NiklasLang No problem. I actually added the link to the answer a few minutes ago. :)